# Use One HTML Slider to Move Handle on Another Slider Without Using JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very simply I'm trying to make multiple HTML 5 sliders that change their values based on the position of other sliders. A simple but illustrative example is when I have two range inputs that should always equal a total value. One starts at value 1 and the other starts at value 10.

```
<input id='slider1' type='range' min='1' max='10' value='1'/>
<input id='slider2' type='range' min='1' max='10' value='10'/>
```

Making the total 11. So, for example, if I move `slider1` to 2, then `slider2` should move down to 9 in order to maintain a total value of 11.

I am able to use an event listener to change the displayed value on the range input using the `.prop()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_total = 11;
    $("#slider1").on("change", function(){
        var slider1 = this.value;
        $("#slider2").prop("value", max_total - slider1);
    });
});
```

However, this doesn't update the position of the handle on the range input. From the research I've done here it seems that everyone says this solution should work, but I'm not sure why it won't work for me. I'm trying to accomplish this without using JQueryUI, by the way.

Here's a JSFiddle of the code I'm using: https://jsfiddle.net/zkdwr784/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling change on slider 2 seems to work -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_total = 11;
    $("#slider1").on("change", function(){
        var slider1 = this.value;
        $("#slider2").prop("value", max_total - slider1);
        $("#slider2").change();
    });
});
```